# Best approach to insert multiple rows on SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, mongodb

Because I'm using a shared Microsoft SQL Server instance, I have started to use MongoDB as it's faster to have around 10 inserts per second.

At the end of the day, I need to read from the MongoDB ([MongoHQ](https://www.mongohq.com/home)) and insert all data into the shared  SQL Server instance (hosting provider).

Currently I'm doing this flow:

1. Get 1000 rows from MongoDB
2. open a connection to SQL Server
3. For each row

   1. insert the data into SQL Server using a stored procedure (as calculations need to be done)
   2. update MongoDb row * (so we don't pick up the processed row later)
4. close the connection to SQL Server
5. `GO TO 1`

And with this, I'm "wasting" around **3 seconds per row**...

Is there a way to **speed things up**?

Currently using C# to perform all the code.

Comment: You don't mention your version, and since you've already pooh-poohed bulk insert / SQlBulkCopy, have you considered table-valued parameters? I talk about them a little here: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql but the bible is here: http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html

Comment: That said, instead of saying "I'm using a stored procedure, so I can't use these other, more efficient methods" you should consider maybe NOT using a stored procedure...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have SQLbulkcopy class to your rescue.

Read more details here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.100).aspx

Thanks,
Naval

Comment: I'm using a store procedure to do the inserts, I don't thing SQLbulkcopy would qualify...

Comment: Is there a reason to using only stored proc?

Comment: MongoDB Has Raw data, and I need to translate to the proper table where has all correct relations...

Comment: You can still read data from MongoDB. The answer given replaces step 3. if Sp is used only since there are additional calculation then either do them at client or insert data in staging table using bulk copy class and do processing on server side.

Answer (score 2):

Please consider BULK INSERT functionality

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

Comment: I'm using a store procedure to do the inserts, I don't thing Bulk Insert would qualify...